# Make a custom URL and link to custom Template

Tags: posts, customization, pages, page-template

I have a set of categories in my WP site. I also have a "team" thing in my site. Now when a user makes a new post he selects a category and then chooses the team to which post belongs.

I have added this team selectbox using meta boxes Now i want to have a link for each team.

How can i do that??..

I though of 2 ways:

(1) - Making a template and linking it to a page called team. So its url becomes : site.com/team/ And now for each team making url like site.com/team/team1 I thought that 2nd url will also be served from my template. But, instead it gave not found.

(2) - Making a custom page for each team.

Is there any other way???

Comment: What is the "team" thing? Is it a Custom Post Type? Is it a Custom Taxonomy?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż It is a  Multi Select box. I have added below the place where you write content for a post. User selects the team from there.

Comment: @SankalpMishra Yes, but how are teams saved? As terms? Post types? Post meta?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic As of now i am storing it in Post Meta. Any suggestion is more than welcome!!!

Comment: If you create [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) `team` & use terms instead, a lot of the hard graft will have been done for you.

Comment: I created a custom taxonomy team and then a template taxonomy-team.php, but, when i did site.com/team..it again gave me page not found!!!